# ajax load hidden div on form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that sends the data to interspire email marketer.

The code for the form below:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.blackbambooliquids.com/email/form.php?form=1" 
id="form" >

....form fields.....

<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
```

The form is sat inside:

```
<div id="form" > the form </div>
```

When the form is submitted, how can I get a thank you message to fade in and the form fields and the div containing them to fade out?

Comment: Paste your JS code in here along with your question

Comment: I dont have any JS code. all the snippets i have tried just havent worked

Comment: As SO isn't a discussion forum, you'll need to show your effort so we have something to critique and troubleshoot.

Comment: Your form element has the same `id` as your `div`. Change one of them to something else. Ids should be unique

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

Assuming

```
<div id="formDiv"><form 
  method="post" 
  action="http://www.blackbambooliquids.com/email/form.php?form=1" 
  id="form" >...</form>
</div>
<div id="thanks">Thank you - hidden in CSS</div>
```

with this in the head

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#form").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $formDiv = $(this).parent();
    $.post(this.action,$(this).serialize(),function() {
      $formDiv.fadeOut(function() {
        $("#thanks").fadeIn();
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: nothing happens, just click the button and nothing, does not sumbit the form or fade out the div

Comment: Any console messages? Do you load jQuery? Do I have spelling mistakes and do the IDs match yours?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="form">
    My form
    <form method="post" id="theForm" ></form>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" /> 
</div>
<div id="thankYou" class='collapsed'>Thank you</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $("#form").fadeOut(function(){
         $("#thankYou").fadeIn();
    })
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yunsmgy2/)

Comment: thats the effect i want but when i click teh submit button it still takes me to the page http://www.blackbambooliquids.com/email/form.php?form=1

Comment: I don't know what that is.. Try to use preventDefault() or something similar, but you asked for the effect..

Comment: This will not work since the click will load a new page

Answer (score 0):

```
guest is this -->[div] is toggle
inside   this -->[div] is a form  
in       this -->[div] the form has a submit button

clicking submit-->sends form data to link
you want to display thank you on the toggle [div] before it goes to target link
```

maybe validation can make it hope so?